# MVVM: How to convert this code behind snippet into an AttachedProperty?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, attached-properties, attachedbehaviors

In WPF, I would like to know how to convert code behind into an attached behavior, as this follows the MVVM pattern and is more maintainable and testable.

I have the following xAML which implements a docking manager:

```
<dxb:BarManager x:Name="MyBarManager"/>
```

In code behind, I could save the layout to an XML file:

```
MyBarManager.SaveLayoutToStream(...);
```

I can also load the layout from an XML file:

```
MyBarManager.LoadLayoutFromStream(...);
```

In order to follow the MVVM pattern, I would like to convert this to an attached property, so instead of having code behind, I could bind to a string `Test` in the ViewModel:

```
<!-- BarManager is part of the framework, it has methods to save/load layout. -->
<dxb:BarManager x:Name="MyBarManager"
     attached:BarLayoutManagerAttachedProperty.DockLayoutSerialize="{Binding Test}">
```

**What I have tried so far**

I used the ReSharper template "dependencyProperty" to create the following attached property, however, there doesn't seem to be a way to hook up any of the calls:

```
public class BarLayoutManagerAttachedProperty : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DockLayoutSerializeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DockLayoutSerialize",
        typeof (BarManager),
        typeof (BarLayoutManagerAttachedProperty),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(BarManager)));

    public static void SetDockLayoutSerialize(DependencyObject element, BarManager value)
    {
        element.SetValue(DockLayoutSerializeProperty, value);
    }

    public static BarManager GetDockLayoutSerialize(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (BarManager) element.GetValue(DockLayoutSerializeProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: In code-behind, you have your **methods**. For xaml, you want attached **properties**. There is something you need to reconsider. Perhaps you need attached **events** or even **behaviours**?

Comment: Have you read this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @dymanoid. Yes, you could be correct. Essentially, if I read the bound property "Test", I want it to call the method ".LoadLayoutToStream", and if I write to the bound property "Test", I want it to call the method ".SaveLayoutToStream". I'm not sure which approach will work.

Comment: @Chris Eelmaa Thanks for the link. I've read right through all of this, but nothing has clicked for me. Am currently watching tutorial videos on dependency properties.

Comment: Could you explain your use case more detailed? When do you need to save and to load the layout?

Comment: @dymanoid Sure. When the project is saved, I want to serialize the layout of the docking manager to a string, and save this as part of the project. When the project is loaded, I want to do the reverse.  I'm actually using DevExpress, the method "SaveLayoutToStream" is a method on the supplied dock manager. Writing is no problem - in the dependency property, I can subscribe to the OnChanged notification. It's the reading thats the issue (is there something equivalent to an OnPropertyRead?). Of course, I could do it all in code behind but that's not as MVVM as I would like.

Comment: I guess I understand now. You want to pass the current layout to the view via binding for layout loading (that's no problem and is a common task for view-to-viewmodel binding); and you want to get the current layout from the view triggered from inside your view model, **but** using the same binding and only it. That's not possible, because your view model cannot (and should not) know if there are any bindings at all. You can use an event in your view model to signal the view that a layout string is needed. BTW, your attached property is wrong: you cannot bind a `BarManager` to a `string`...

Comment: @dymanoid Thanks for the feedback, much appreciated. I think I know what to do now. I'll post a complete solution when I get it working (probably tomorrow).